# Verify if any values are present in any set

Tags: python

How can I verify if any value is contained in any of the variables with an if statement? I'm looking for something like:

```
if "foo","bar","spam","eggs" in test1,test2:
```

This would return true if any of the four values were found in any of the test1, test2 variables. What type should test1,test2 be ?

Later edit:
What if I have a list so it would be something like:

```
test1=['foo','abc','def']
if {'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'} in test1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [set intersections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
if {test1, test2} & {'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'}:
    # true if there is an intersection between the two sets.
```

So if one of `test1` and `test2` is set to one of the four values in the other set, the test will be true.

If you need *both* `test1` and `test2` to be using values from the other set, you'd test for a *subset*:

```
if {test1, test2} <= {'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'}:
    # true if all values in the first set are also in the second
```

Comment: What if I have a list so it would be something like: `test1=['foo','abc','def']; if test1 & {'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'}` ?

Comment: This is most pythonic way but note that if `test1` and `test2` be `set` objects you can not put them within a `set`.

Comment: @Kasra: which is unlikely here since we are testing against strings, but yes, using a set requires that the values all are hashable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression within [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
any(i in j for j in [test1,test2] for i in my_var)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> my_var={"foo","bar","spam","eggs"}
>>> test1={'a','b'}
>>> test2={'c','d'}
>>> 
>>> any(i in j for j in [test1,test2] for i in my_var)
False
>>> test2={'c','foo'}
>>> any(i in j for j in [test1,test2] for i in my_var)
True
```